# Integrating an ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE:
$$
\frac{d\varphi_0}{dt}(t) = \nu(t) e^{-\nu(t)} - q_0 \varphi_0(t) + q_K \varphi_K(t) (1-e^{-\nu(t)})
$$
with: $\nu: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ some function, $q_0, q_K$ real numbers and $\varphi_K:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ some function. I have the boundary condition $\varphi_0(0) = \phi_0$. The text I'm reading states that this implies that we have:
$$
\varphi_0(t) = e^{-q_0t} \phi_0 + \int_0^t e^{q_0 (s-t)} \left(\nu(s) e^{-\nu(s)} + q_K \varphi_K(s) (1-e^{-\nu(s)})\right) ds
$$
I guess this is a pretty straightforward calculation but I don't know how to do it. Any tips/answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, call

$$
f(t) = \nu(t)e^{-\nu(t)}  + q_K \varphi_K(t) (1-e^{-\nu(t)})
$$

So that you original problem becomes

$$
\frac{d\varphi_0}{dt} + q_0 \varphi_0 = f(t) \tag{1}
$$

Assume there exists a function $g(t)$ such that when I multiply it at both sides of (1), I get a total derivative on the l.h.s:

\begin{eqnarray}
g(t)\frac{d\varphi_0}{dt} + q_0 g(t)\varphi_0 &=& g(t)f(t) = \frac{d}{dt}[g(t)\varphi_0(t)]\\
\Rightarrow~~~~ g(t)\frac{d\varphi_0}{dt}  + \frac{dg}{dt}\varphi_0(t) &=& g(t)\frac{d\varphi_0}{dt} + q_0 g(t)\varphi_0  \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

this last equation is only true if

$$
\frac{dg}{dt} = q_0 g(t) ~~~~\Rightarrow~~~~ g(t) =e^{q_0 t} \tag{3}
$$

Evaluating this result in (2) we get

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{q_0t}\varphi(t) \right] = e^{q_0(t)}f(t)
$$

which can be easily solved for $\varphi_0(t)$:

$$
e^{q_0 t}\varphi_0(t)- \left. e^{q_0 t}\varphi_0(t)\right|_{t=0} =\int_0^t ds~e^{q_0s}f(s) 
$$

which you can easily rearrange to

$$
\phi_0(t) = e^{-q_0t}\varphi_0(0)+\int_0^t ds~e^{q_0(s - t)}f(s) \tag{4}
$$

This method is called the [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) method and in general you can appply it to problems of the form

$$
\frac{du}{dx} + a(x)u(x) = b(x)
$$

Comment: Awesome, thanks very good answer!

Comment: Do you know of a good reference book/course where methods like these are described or will any standard book on ODEs suffice?

Comment: @HolyMonk My genuine pleasure. Any book on ODEs should cover this

Comment: In your textbook, look for "first order linear" differential equation.